# Converting dictionary to KeyedVectorFormat

Tags: word2vec

I tried to use the code here :
[Convert Python dictionary to Word2Vec object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45981305/convert-python-dictionary-to-word2vec-object)

The error does not make sense. I wrote the file in non-binary format and the first line is as it should be.
Any idea what might be going wrong?
Or another way to achieve the same end result?

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py in load_word2vec_format(cls, fname, fvocab, binary, encoding, unicode_errors, limit, datatype)
   1496         return _load_word2vec_format(
   1497             cls, fname, fvocab=fvocab, binary=binary, encoding=encoding, unicode_errors=unicode_errors,
-> 1498             limit=limit, datatype=datatype)
   1499 
   1500     def get_keras_embedding(self, train_embeddings=False):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/utils_any2vec.py in _load_word2vec_format(cls, fname, fvocab, binary, encoding, unicode_errors, limit, datatype)
    392                 parts = utils.to_unicode(line.rstrip(), encoding=encoding, errors=unicode_errors).split(" ")
    393                 if len(parts) != vector_size + 1:
--> 394                     raise ValueError("invalid vector on line %s (is this really the text format?)" % line_no)
    395                 word, weights = parts[0], [datatype(x) for x in parts[1:]]
    396                 add_word(word, weights)

ValueError: invalid vector on line 1 (is this really the text format?)
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what code you're running; you could show it here, in your question, to help answerers understand. Also, that error is a strong indication the file you've attempted to `load_word2vec_format()` is **not** in a proper format. Especially if it's a text file, you should be able to excerpt its 1st ~3 lines here, to show exactly what's amiss. Alternatively, you could say more about your original data – what are you starting with, that you want to get into a `KeyedVectors` object?

Comment: "13450 300
cuttlefish 0.07333286 0.046717547 -0.018069735 0.017946262 -0.0588368 " This is the start of the file. The file contains 13450 word vectors, and each is 300 dimensions. The first is "cuttlefish" . The file is in the correct format , looks exactly like other KeyedVector file. I have 2 lists - one has vectors and the other has words. I am converting to the KeyedVector format so that I can use gensim libraries to do analysis. The link I mention in my post is the exact code I am running with no changes. I just ask for the file in a non binary format.

Comment: It's hard to evaluate the file excerpt in a comment; showing the lines in the question text (quoted for exact whitespace/linebreak preservation) is the best way to share the relevant info. For example: get the output of `head -2 YOURFILE`, edit it into your question between `\`\`\`` lines. The error indicates the file has an issue, and at the very front, so it's just a matter of identifying what's wrong.